# Windows Service is started but does not do anything - .NET

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-services

I have a .NET Windows Service (.NET 3.5) with a timer (`System.Timers.Timer`). The `OnElapsed` method looks like this:

```
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            //process some stuff here..
            ProcessStuff();
            timer.Interval = GetTimerInterval();
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

It works fine until it mysteriously stops working. This happens every x days and although the service has a status of started, it does not kick off the `ProcessStuff`() method. I use `log4net` and nothing is logged there or in the Windows Event logs. The `ProcessStuff`() spawns multiple threads to do some work.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: We're gonna need more data than that to diagnose what's going on...  Have you tried attaching a debugger to examine the state of the threads in the service?  Depending on what ProcessStuff() and GetTimerInterval() do, you could just be hanging somewhere waiting for those functions to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that `ProcessStuff()` or `GetTimerInterval()` throws an exception, so that `timer.Start()` is not executed?

Then you should maybe wrap that part in a `try..catch` and/or add some logging, e.g:

```
timer.Stop();
try
{
  //process some stuff here..
  ProcessStuff();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // log the exception?
}
timer.Interval = GetTimerInterval();
timer.Start();
```

Comment: It's possible but why would it happen only after x days. I do see unhandled exceptions in ProcessStuff log and the timer still works

Comment: to be sure you might also add a global exception handle that logs to system event viewer  "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException"

Comment: @DotnetDude: it's difficult to answer without knowing what these methods do.

Comment: @Martin - I will add the try catch block. Are you suggesting that in the catch block, i try to restart the timer?

Comment: @DotnetDude: no you'll have to restart it after the catch block. Otherwise it will only be started if an exception was thrown. I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas for you.  One create a dump and see what is up or use the remote debugger and see what you are locking on.

Comment: How would I create a dump? Can you please explain